# /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./file)

Tags: gcc, version, upgrade, glibc, kde-plasma

I'm using KDE Neon 5.25 and it came with GCC 9 version by default.
Though, when trying to run a file by executing it (./file) it throws me an error:

/usr/lib/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.34 not found (required by ./file)

I did some research and also saw that this file was compiled with GCC 12.

So I updated to GCC 12, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

> So I updated to GCC 12, but the problem persists.

The problem persists because it has *nothing* to do with the version of GCC.

The problem is that the binary you are using was built on a system with GLIBC-2.34 (or above) and you are using on a system with GLIBC-2.33 (or below).

You need to get a binary that was built for your distribution.

Alternatively you could try to upgrade your system to newer GLIBC, but this is not recommended -- any mistake will likely render your system unbootable.